# Trying to convert script using PUSHD/POPD from BASH to ZSH

Tags: bash, zsh, pushd

I am trying to convert the following script from BASH to ZSH and the POPD just won't work... Could someone help me please?

```
runMyScript() {
  if [[ -e $PROJECTS_HOME/myFolder/myScript.sh]]; then
    pushd $PROJECTS_HOME/myFolder > dev/null
    . ./myScript.sh
    popd > dev/null
  else
    ... //Do something else instead
  fi
}
runMyScript
```

The error is this

```
myScript:popd:5: directory stack empty
```

Now I know what this means, but I don't seem to be able to fix it... I am also struggling to find a meaningful fix as well.

If I run the script manually, it seems to work fine, but if I run it by calling runMyScript that's when it seems to fail.

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: It's unlikely that a real error msg is being sent to std-out, but I would remove the `>/dev/null`s from your script and then add shell debugging with `set -vx` before and `set +vx` after the problematic code. You''d also do well to include a real warning msg in the `else` branch. Then you know exactlyl what is happening, and then you can figure out why it is happening. It can't hurt to surround all your variable w dbl-quotes, i.e. `"$MyVar"`. Good luck.

Comment: "directory stack empty" is a normal answer popd on stderr when there was no change of the directory, I do not know what your script does, so it's hard to say anything more. By the way
  > redirects stdout and not stderr, and this to a null file in the ./dev directory which probably does not exist instead of the system /dev/null

Comment: @Takuhii : From this message, I would conclude that the `pushd` failed, but you did not say that you get an error message from pushd. Could it be that you overlooked it? Run the script again and post the complete output (copy and paste). In general, it would be a good idea to handle a failed pushd in the code, for instance `pushd $PROJECTS_HOME/myFolder || exit 1`.

Comment: Thank you @shellter this put me on the right track, my script is now working thank you :)

Comment: @user1934428 pushd seems to work fine, no error messages :(

Comment: @user1934428 noticed something I missed (the missing inintial `/` char that should be part of `/dev/null` ). That explains one class of problem. If you don't need/want the output from `pushd/popd` you can redirect std-out and std-err using `... > /dev/null 2&1`. Glad you sorted your problem, good luck.

Comment: @Takuhii : Can't be. Run the script with `-x` and show us the output. There must be some oddity going on.

Comment: @sheliter : Double-quoting the variables is unnecessary. According to the OP, he is running the script under Zsh.

Answer (score 1):

I altered the script based on some feedback from @shellter and the script now seems to be working... the new code looks like this;

```
runMyScript() {
  if [ -f "$PROJECTS_HOME"/myFolder/myScript.sh]; then
    pushd "$PROJECTS_HOME"/myFolder
    . ./myScript.sh
    popd
  else
    // CREATE the variables needed to run this script
  fi
}
runMyScript
```

Comment: Great that it works, but the `>dev/null` redirection, while unnecessary in the original, can not have done any harm, as you can verify easily by doing a `pushd $HOME; popd >/dev/null` on the command line.

Comment: Except of the removal of the unnecessary redirections, I don't see any changes to your original script. What else did you change?